# How to read in com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist with Swift on macOS?

Tags: swift, plist, codable, property-list

I am trying to read a value from this property list file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

to see if some Hotkey is enabled.
I tried to read the plist file with Codable:

```
import Foundation

let xml = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>AppleSymbolicHotKeys</key>
    <dict>
    <key>10</key>
    <dict>
        <key>enabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>value</key>
        <dict>
            <key>parameters</key>
            <array>
                <integer>65535</integer>
                <integer>96</integer>
                <integer>8650752</integer>
            </array>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>standard</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>11</key>
    <dict>
        <key>enabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>value</key>
        <dict>
            <key>parameters</key>
            <array>
                <integer>65535</integer>
                <integer>97</integer>
                <integer>8650752</integer>
            </array>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>standard</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
    """

struct Root: Codable {
    var AppleSymbolicHotKeys: Hotkey

    struct Hotkey: Codable {
        var someKey: Property // << key is an integer, not a static key!
    
        struct Property: Codable {
            var enabled: Bool
            var value: Value
        
            struct Value: Codable {
                var parameter: [Int]
                var type: String
            }
        }
    }
}
  
if let data = xml.data(using: .utf8) {
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    let hotkeys = try? decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print("Decoded:", hotkeys)
}
```

In my Playground, it returns:

```
Decoded: nil
```

In the above code, I copied a part of the xml contents for reference. I tried with reading the real file too, it returns data but is not decoding.

**I understand that `someKey` in my model can not work, since each "key" has a new numeric value, but how can I make it work?**

Comment: In a property list a `<key>` is always `String`. In `Root` decode `let AppleSymbolicHotKeys: [String:Property]` and delete the struct `Hotkey` but not `Property`. And `parameter` is actually `parameters`.

Comment: Brilliant @vadian, decode works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the model struct looks following the advice of @vadian, and it works:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    var AppleSymbolicHotKeys: [String: Property]
    
    struct Property: Codable {
        var enabled: Bool
        var value: Value
        
        struct Value: Codable {
            var parameters: [Int]
            var type: String
        }
    }
}
```